# Get Unique/Distinct results for SQL Query on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables: products and reviews, where each product has many reviews:

table products has the following columns: id, name
table reviews has the following columns: id, productid, created_on, rating, review.  Where the productid is a foreign key, and created_on is type datetime.

Sample data as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>product id</th>
    <th>product name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>review id</th>
    <th>product id</th>
    <th>rating</th>
    <th>review</th>
    <th>created_on</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Perfect foo</td>
    <td>2017-1-1Z00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This foo is not the foo I was looking for</td>
    <td>2017-2-2Z00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Foo-tastic</td>
    <td>2017-3-3Z00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Bar is Bar/10</td>
    <td>2017-3-3Z00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Barmendous!!!</td>
    <td>2017-1-1Z00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to get the latest review for each product but I'm unsure how to do it. It should be something like:

```
SELECT products.product_name, reviews.rating, reviews.review FROM products LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = reviews.productid ORDER BY reviews.created_on DESC;
```

But this will return multiple results for each product.  I only need one review for each product, preferably the most recent review.

MySQL 5.x or above is the preferred database in this case.

Sample out is as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>product name</th>
    <th>rating</th>
    <th>review</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Footastic</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Bar is Bar/10</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: How do you decide which one is latest? Is there any date column which signifies the same?

Comment: Please include sample data and your expected output.  Without table structure, I don't think an exact answer can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the latest review for each product, then use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT p.product_name, r.*
FROM products p LEFT JOIN 
     reviews r
     ON p.id = r.productid AND
        r.created_on = (SELECT MAX(r2.created_on)
                        FROM reviews r2
                        WHERE r2.productid = r.productid
                       );
```

Comment: ahhhhh this makes sense.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Do your query around the other way:

```
SELECT r.*, p.*
FROM reviews AS r
LEFT JOIN products AS p
    ON p.id = r.productid
GROUP BY r.productid 
ORDER BY r.date DESC;
```

Comment: You should format your answers so that they are readable.  This one is on the house.

Comment: thanks, updated it with sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Doing a `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` is simply wrong.  Thinking that that `ORDER BY` is before the `GROUP BY` is wrong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff apart from the table names the query works fine for me, can you tell me why it's wrong? `ORDER BY` also isn't before `GROUP BY`? I've updated the query to use the aliases as I missed this in my initial response.